# Editing and saving any datatable in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i need editing, deleting, adding functions and after that save the file, how  can i do that? 
I have datatable and I'm showing datatable in view.

This is datatable getting from other class every time datatable is different

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult LocalFileHandlerAction()
{
    DataTableModel model2 = new DataTableModel()
    {
        dataTableForXml = DataTypeControl.dataTableFinaly

    };

    return View(model2);

}
```

and this is my view code it show datatable With foreach

```
@model ValueMapping.WebUI.Models.DataTableModel

@using System.Data; 

@using System.Web.Helpers

<div id="ListView">


<table style="font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:11px;
    color:#333333;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #666666;
    border-collapse: collapse;"> 
    <thead> 
    <tr> 
    @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.dataTableForXml.Columns)     
    {          
        <th  style="border: 1px solid; width:140px"; font-size:15px>@col.ColumnName</th> 
    }     
    </tr> 
    </thead>         
    <tbody> 
    @foreach (DataRow row in Model.dataTableForXml.Rows)     
    {         
        <tr> 
        @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.dataTableForXml.Columns)         
        {              
            <td style="border: 1px solid; width:140px; font-size:15px">@row[col.ColumnName]</td> 
        }         
        </tr> 
    }     
    </tbody> 
</table>

 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a form with the values you would like to save.

Then create a new controller that gets the model with the values you send in the get method.

(Note: The attribute GET is not required as the default is already a get)

Your controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LocalFileHandlerAction(DataTableModel DataTableModel)
{
   // Validate model
   if(ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      // Save logic
   }

    return View(DataTableModel);

}
```

Comment: i'm uderstand it I want to know how can I edit table rows and column in view